What are the numbers trying to say?
These numbers are trying to tell you something about them, but what could it be?

Starter hint:

 _ _ _ _ / _ _ / _ _ _ _ / _ _ _

Helpful hint:

 _ u _ _ / _ e / _ _ _ _ / _ _ _

Attribution: I came up with this one myself.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

I came up with this one myself. I just am not sure how to mention this.

You can edit a question by clicking the "edit" button below the tags

Could you give a hint?

Just added 2 hints

Just want to ask, this doesn't require some non-trivial knowledge right?

No, it does not. Unfortunately when I made this one, I did not put a whole lot of effort into making sure the puzzle was enjoyable to solve, so it might be kinda annoying to reach the answer. I might put out an improved variant of this later though

I might have an answer, are you sure the third column is correct.

@Mike Yes, the third column is correct
